# Unit tests with WireMock works locally but fail in Azure pipelines

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The below code works when running locally, but when I try to deploy it to our test environments on `Azure DevOps pipeline` I get `InternalServerError`.

**IntegrationTests.cs:**

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    if (testContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testContext));

    _server = WireMockServer.Start();
    _webAppFactory = new TestWebApplicationFactory<Program>(testContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName, _server.Urls[0]);
    _httpClient = _webAppFactory.CreateClient();

    InitializeDatabase(testContext);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task InitReturnsOK()
{
    var expectedInitOutput = new InitOutputModel
    {
        IsSuccessStatusCode = true,
        OrderRef = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    };

    TestUtils.ConfigureServerResponse(_server, Constants.InitUrl, HttpStatusCode.OK, expectedInitOutput);

    var response = await Init().ConfigureAwait(false);

    response.Should().BeSuccessful();

    var initOutput = await TestUtils.GetContentObject<InitOutputModel>(response.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);

    initOutput.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedInitOutput, options => options.Excluding(x => x.OrderTime));
}
```

The error message:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Failed InitReturnsOK [43 s]
  Error Message:
   Expected HttpStatusCode to be successful (2xx), but found HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError {value: 500}.
  Stack Trace:
     at FluentAssertions.Execution.LateBoundTestFramework.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
   at FluentAssertions.Primitives.HttpResponseMessageAssertions`1.BeSuccessful(String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at MyCompany.Service.Tests.WebApp.IntegrationTests.BankIdIntegrationTests.InitReturnsOK() in D:\11899\s\MyCompany.Service.Tests\WebApp.IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

**What have I missed here?**

Comment: If you are using the Microsoft hosted agent, you can try creating a self-hosted agent locally and run the pipeline on the self-hosted agent to see if it works. If it works, then we need to check Environment Differences between them. You can also enable the variable “[system.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) ”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline, then trigger a new pipeline and check the detailed logs. It may help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some logs in my code (`Console.WriteLine`) and found out that I was doing calls to `Redis cache` in my integration tests which `Azure pipeline` didn't like. So I mocked the Redis class so that it used `Memory Cache` instead and then it worked.